# Pass route parameter from jquery variable in blade view

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

How to add the `delete_id = $(this).attr('delete_id');` jquery variable in the `'product_id' => ????` of the ajax `url`

I have this route: 
`Route::delete('/{store}/{table_name}_{table_id}/{receipt_id}/shop/cart/{product_id}', 'Cart\CartController@destroy')->name('cart.destroy');`

and this ajax:

```
 $(document).on('submit','#cartItem_delete',function(e){
        delete_id = $(this).attr('delete_id');
         var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //prepare form data for Ajax post
        $.ajax({
          type: "DELETE",
          url: '{{ route('cart.destroy', ['product_id' => ????, 'store' => $store, 'table_name' => $table_name, 'table_id' => $table_id, 'receipt_id' => $receipt_id]) }}',
          dataType:"json", //expect json value from server
          data: form_data
        }).done(function(data){ //on Ajax success    
                $('tr[row='+delete_id+']').remove();
                $('.cart-button a span').text(data.count);
                if (data.count < 1) {
                    $('.container #cartContainer').remove();
                    location.reload();
                }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

The html form is in a `foreach` statement (for each row in the cart) and the row id is in the `delete_id` attribute:

```
<form id="cartItem_delete" delete_id="{{ $item->rowId }}" class="side-by-side">
                                {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" value="Remove">Remove</button>
                            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add action attribute to form with url:

```
<form action="{{ route('cart.destroy', ['product_id' => $item->rowId, 'store' => $store, 'table_name' => $table_name, 'table_id' => $table_id, 'receipt_id' => $receipt_id]) }}"...
```

then get url in submit event:

```
var action_url = $( this ).attr('action')
```

and pass it to ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: action_url
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options

1. pass the value as a ajax param and then you will need to change the route and controller
2. you build the url and append the id via javascript

`url: "{{url('/')}}/{{$store}}/{{$table_name}}/{{$receipt_id}}/shop/cart/"+delete_id`